# Do ECMAScript 2016 decorators make TypeScript decorators redundant?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-next

TypeScript is a strict superset of ECMAScript 2015 and already has a decorator support. Does it mean with introduction of  ECMAScript 2016 decorators, TypeScript decorators become redundant or Does it mean going forward TypeScript has to change its underlying implementation to generate  ECMAScript 2016 decorators?

Comment: as long as 90% of the time you are generating ES5 you don't really care about it... Both es2016 and typescript will be transformed to something else

Comment: true but I am talking about the time when typescript no longer generates ES5.

Comment: Decorators are not part of ES2016.

Answer (score 4):

As it states in the [docs regarding decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):

> Decorators are an experimental feature that may change in future
>   releases

Typescript lets you use future features that aren't still implemented in all js environments by compiling the output into js that matches the target environment.

So for example this:

```
function deco(constructor: Function) { }

@deco
class A { }
```

Compiles into:

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
function deco(constructor) { }
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    return A;
}());
A = __decorate([
    deco
], A);
```

As you can see the js version contains everything that is needed to make it work.
If something changes then yes, the compiler will change to output the right js.

Comment: See I don't understand any bit of the generated code `__decorate`, if underling implementation is changed for transpiler it would definitely make code more readable for people like me, though not sure reablity is at all a tenet of the transpiler and thay would prefer to continue to generate the same way until something breaks.

Comment: The compiled js isn't meant to be readable, it is meant to work and have as little footprint as possible.  You shouldn't be changing the compiled js yourself, and you should trust that the compiler will output the right code based on the target you specified.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 I guess what you're asking is whether TS decorators will eventually compile to ES decorators. That's a fair question, I don't think we know the answer to that yet, but I would expect this is likely. There is already `ES2016, ES2017, ESNext` targets but I don't know if the compiler emits ES decorators for any of those targets (yet), nor do I know if they are even compatible specs at this point. I'd like to know this, too!

Comment: It would be very useful to not have it transpile the decorators. I've working with a downstream transpiler that deals with them for me, part of a wider build environment. So I'd like them output verbatim. Short of hacking the compiler it doesn't seem obvious how.

Comment: @RichardCorfield I'm not sure what you mean. As far as I'm aware most js runtime environments still don't support decorators. How do you expect them to run if you don't want to use the output of the ts compiler (or babel)

Comment: I believe the downstream process, which I don't control, uses Babel. So it accepts decorators in its input. It doesn't give me Types though, hence my research to put Typescript in front of it. My brief for a two week research project is "Can we use Typescript for..."

I've asked the owner of the downstream process if they can consider supporting Typescript, which would make more sense to make the process a single step. I can imagine having two compile steps that don't talk will cause other confusion.

Comment: I've explored the TSC code now and gained an understanding of how it works. I'd need to modify the Typescript Transformer (ts.ts) to not translate decorators and instead move that logic down to the ES2017 transformer or whatever next. (Or maybe even its own mini transformer that can be inserted in the right place. That would make the code quite self contained giving all the benefits of better encapsulation and isolation of concerns that come from it.) That would be quite a large change.

Comment: @RichardCorfield I don't understand why you care what the output of the ts compiler looks like. Regardless of decorators, it's not fun to work with. If you only then feed it into another processor then what difference does it make? Another thing is that babel 7 now supports typescript (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/08/27/typescript-and-babel-7/) so maybe just use that?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll look at the Babel Typescript input.

I don't have control of the eventual process that handles my script. It's transpiled again. I've already found that the downstream process is quite fussy about its input. I can't add more information as it's all experimental stuff. When it's finally released maybe I'll remember to come back and fill in the details :-)

My brief really is "to see if we can use Typescript for this environment" fitting in with the processing that the environment mandates. It's poking around that makes me conclude that the environment uses Babel.